# Why is there difference in functions behavior in Java and C++?

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, tree

I was coding intervies questions at LeetCode.com and faced an issue trying to submit a solution of "Validate Binary Search Tree" problem. The solution code, written in Java, looks like this:

```
public boolean helper(TreeNode node, Integer lower, Integer upper) {
if (node == null) return true;
}

int val = node.val;
if (lower != null && val <= lower) return false;
if (upper != null && val >= upper) return false;

if (! helper(node.right, val, upper)) return false;
if (! helper(node.left, lower, val)) return false;
return true;
}

public boolean isValidBST(TreeNode root) {
    return helper(root, null, null);}
```

However, when I implement the very same algorythm on C++, it doesn't work correctly, for example, in [0,null,-1] test case. There's the code:

```
bool isValidBST(TreeNode* root) {
    return checkSubtree(root, NULL, NULL);
}
bool checkSubtree(TreeNode* node, int lower, int upper) {
    if (node == NULL) return true;

    int val = node->val;
    if (lower != NULL && val <= lower) return false;
    if (upper != NULL && val >= upper) return false;

    if (! checkSubtree(node->right, val, upper)) return false;
    if (! checkSubtree(node->left, lower, val)) return false;
    return true;
  }
```

Why is it so? Maybe there's something wrong in NULL notation, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Maybe because those are totally different languages?

Comment: What is [0,null,-1] test case? [0,null,-1] is not a tree

Comment: @Amongalen however these functions are straightforward translations of each other, which should do the same thing.

Comment: In the current form the Java code won't even compile. There are too many closing brackets.

Comment: `NULL` is not an `int` and should not be used as one. Actually it shouldnt be used at all anymore, since there is `nullptr`

Comment: @user253751 - No they shouldn't. C++ has a different object model. A translation that ignores that will never do the same things.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and explain the meaning of "it doesn't work correctly"

Comment: `Integer` in Java can be `null` (since that's really just a pointer under the hood). The `int` in C++ isn't a pointer. If an `int` is `0` and you check wheter it is `NULL`, you get `true`. In Java, the `Integer` can be `null` and it's not the same thing as `0`.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Uh, can you point to one line in this function that is not equivalent between the C++ and Java versions?! (It's the function header. in C++, `int` isn't nullable. That is the answer to the question. The rest is equivalent)

Comment: @user253751 - Yeah, `int` and `NULL` don't interact the same as `Integer` and `null`. That is a major lack of equivalence, so don't cop out on it after making a sweeping claim.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica And the reason is not "because those are totally different languages". The reason is "because null is different". Otherwise we could never write programs because English is totally different to C++, so we could never write C++ code that does the same thing as an English specification.

Comment: @user253751 - No, the reason is as I said, a different object model, and ignoring it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C++, `NULL` is ["an implementation-defined null pointer constant"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL), typically written as `0`. `0` is a valid way to write a null pointer in C++. It also happens to be a valid `int` value.

In Java, `(Integer)0` and `null` are not the same thing.

In Java, `lower != null` checks whether there is no lower bound. In C++, `lower != NULL` checks whether the lower bound is not 0. If there's a 0 in your tree, your C++ program gets confused because it thinks there is no lower/upper bound for that part of the tree.